# size of linkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm very new to Java, and I was given this Linkedlist set-up, I need to use recursion or while loop to write the size function that return the size of the linkedList. I guess I'm very confused as to how to do the size function when this linkedlist setup doesn't initialize Node, head etc.

```
package list;

public class LinkedList {
  public int value;
  public LinkedList next;

  public LinkedList (int value, LinkedList next) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = next;
  }

  public static LinkedList list () {
    return new LinkedList(1, new LinkedList(2, new LinkedList(3, null)));
  }

  public int size () {
    int size = 0;
    Node Current = head;
    while(Current.next != null)
    {
      Current = Current.next;
      size++;     
    }
    return size;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your LinkedList class looks an awful lot like a Node.  Usually it's the Node which has a value and a pointer to the next element, and the LinkedList has values like `head` and methods like `add()` and `size()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your current formulation, your `LinkedList` instances are actually nodes as well as lists.  That's OK, but it means that there is no distinguished "head" of the list ...

In this context, the fix is to change:

```
    Node Current = head;
```

to

```
    LinkedList current = this;
```

(And, yes, the `size` variable should start as `1`.  In this formulation, an empty list is represented by `null`.  If you are calling `size()` on an instance of `LinkedList`, then the size of the list must be at least 1.)

---

@Konrad states *"A list itself should encapsulate the nodes."*

Actually that is a design choice.  If you are following OO design principles then it should.  However, there are situations where pragmatically you don't want to do that.  Sometimes it is necessary to "sacrifice" abstraction to get better performance or reduce memory utilization.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of computing size in a linked list like the one you've created is to use recursion. There are only two cases:

1. A linked list with no next has size `1` - just itself
2. A linked list with a next has size `1` plus the size of the next.

Thus, we have the following function:

```
public int size(){
    if(next == null){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 1 + next.size();
    }
}
```

This can be written extremely concisely using a ternary operator:

```
public int size(){
    return next != null ? 1 + next.size() : 1;
}
```

For the iterative solution, there's no need to use the `Node` class, as each `LinkedList` object represents both itself (one single value) and all of the values to follow (a list of values). From that point of view, we have to loop from "here" until there is nowhere else to go.

```
public int size () {
   int size = 1;
   LinkedList Current = this;
   while(Current.next != null){
     Current = Current.next;
     size++;     
   }
   return size;
}
```

Comment: What is `tail` though?  In the given problem all we have is `value` and `next`.  Perhaps if `tail` were changed to `next` it would make more sense, especially in terms of the question asked.

Comment: Haha yeah. Didn't think about the wording of the problem and went with the LinkedList implementation in my head. Changed to `next`.

Comment: While recursion works for small lists, if you tried to calculate the size of a long list this way you would get a StackOverflowError.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int size()
{
    int size = 1;
    LinkedList head = this;
    while (head.next != null)
    {
        head = head.next;
        size++;
    }

    return size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it like:

```
public int size () {
    int size = 0;
    // set the head as current note
    Node current = head;
    // while a current node is set
    while(current != null)
    {
      // increment site
      size++;     
      // and set the next as current node
      current = current.next;
    }
    return size;
}
```

The list itself is not a list. It's a linked list of nodes. A list itself should encapsulate the nodes.